# How to apply a linear transformation to a data frame using coefficients from a linear regression?

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
id.v <- 1:100
treatment.v <- sample(c("Treatment", "Control"), 100, replace = TRUE)
income.v <- sample(50000:100000, 100, replace = TRUE)
gender.v <- sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE)
race.v <- sample(c("White", "Asian", 
                   "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
                   "Hispanic or Latino", "African American", 
                   "Two or more races"), 100, replace = TRUE)
age.v <- sample(50:95, 100, replace = TRUE)

regression.df <- data.frame(id = id.v, 
                             treatment = treatment.v, 
                             income = income.v,
                             gender = gender.v,
                             race = race.v,
                             age = age.v)
```

and I apply a linear regression on only the treated observations

```
results.lm <- lm(income ~ gender + race + age, 
                 data = regression.df %>% filter(treatment == "Treatment"))
```

I store the coefficients in a data frame called `model_coef.df`.

```
model_coef.df <- data.frame(Covar = names(coef(results.lm)),
                            Beta = unname(coef(results.lm))) %>% 
  filter(Covar != "(Intercept)")
```

I basically would like to apply a linear transformation on the entire, unfiltered `regression.df` based on the Beta column in `model_coef.df`. I know there is a built in R function called `predict` but this will only give me the predicted values of the inputted data set (`regression.df` filtered for `treatment` = Treated).

My problem is, I am having trouble matching the `Beta` column in `model_coef.df` to the column values in regression.df, specifically for the factor variables `race` and `gender`. Right now, I only have 7 coefficients, my original data set has 92 coefficients because I have a handful of factor columns.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel here. You can simply use the `newdata` argument in `predict`. That is, use `predict(results.lm, newdata = regression.df)`. This will predict values for _all_ the rows of `regression.df`, not just the 'Treatment' entries.

Comment: I don't understand why you think predict will not work for all records. When you use `predict`, it basically replaced the `data=` parameter from your `lm` completely so that filter is ignored. If you run `predict(results.lm,  regression.df)` it will return predictions for all 100 records

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron!!! Of course there is an obvious solution. I appreciate the help!